# docker CMD command for nginx with config specified

Tags: docker

I have the following CMD in my docker command:

```
CMD ["nginx", "-c", "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

But it is not picking up the `-c` switch.

WHen I run this in the container:

`nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -g "daemon off;"` it woks as expected.

Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: That looks right. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: If you can access the container maybe try to check the nginx logs in search for what's the command line processed by docker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your syntax is wrong:

```
CMD ["nginx", "-c", "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

No comma after "nginx.conf" before "-g"...